# Fazer uma chamada httprequest com cURL

Tags: php, json

Tenho url de uma api que me retorna um json, e queria fazer um pedido para que a informação fosse atualizada, e despois descodificada atraves do json_decode, pelo que sei teria que fazer uma httprequest  em que usava o cURL e depois o json_decode. Não sei se me fiz entender , espero que sim e que me ajudem , obrigada

Comment: Se não entenderem tento explicar melhor, obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) para isso, basta você pegar o valor a cada alteração em dos checkbox das classes de aposta e tipo e atribuir o valor do checkbox marcado a coluna da tabela bilhete desejada:

```js
$(".cb").change(function(){
    $(".cb").prop('checked',false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    $("#aposta").html($(this).val());
});


$(".chb").change(function(){
    $(".chb").prop('checked',false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    if($(this).val() == "myselect"){
      $("#tipo").html($("#myselect").val());
    }else{
      $("#tipo").html($(this).val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <form>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="chb" value="Simples (de 1 a 8)" />Simples (de 1 a 8)
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="chb" value="Combinada (de 2 a 8)" />Combinada (de 2 a 8)
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="chb" value="myselect" />
        <select id="myselect" class="chb" style= "width: 90px;">
          <option value="Múltipla">Múltipla</option>
          <option value="2/3 combinações">2/3 combinações</option>
          <option value="2/4 combinações">2/4 combinações</option>
          <option value="2/5 combinações">2/5 combinações</option>
          <option value="3/4 combinações">3/4 combinações</option>
          <option value="3/5 combinações">3/5 combinações</option>
          <option value="4/5 combinações">4/5 combinações</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <script>
      $(".chb").change(function()
                {
                    $(".chb").prop('checked',false);
                    $(this).prop('checked',true);
                });
      </script>
  </form>
  </div>    
  <div class="col-md-2">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
  <form>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb" value="1€" />1€</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb"  value="2€"/>2€</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb" value="5€" />5€</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb" value="10€" />10€</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb" value="20€" />20€</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb" value="50€" />50€</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb" value="75€"/>75€</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="cb" value="100€" />100€</label>
  </form>
</div>
<br />
<div class="panel-footer panel-primary ticketFooterTour">
  <table class="table table-condensed text-center" border="1">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Tipo</th>
            <th class="text-center">Odd</th>
            <th class="text-center">Aposta</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
            <th class="text-center">Resultado</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center" id="tipo"></td>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center" id="aposta"></td>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada mesmo :)

Comment: E é possível que quando seleccionar múltipla abra logo o dropdown com as opções ? Obrigada

Comment: Não sei se é possível, tentei simular aqui e não deu certo. Inclusive abri uma pergunta se quiser acompanhar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275504/expandir-opções-de-um-elemento-select-através-de-javascript

Comment: acompanho sim , obrigada