# Expandir opções de um elemento select ao clicar em botão

Tags: javascript, html

É possível forçar a exibição das opções de um elemento `<select>` através de javascript?

A ideia é simular o clique do um usuário no `select`.
 Imagine que eu tenho um `select` desabilitado, e ao clicar em um botão ele fica habilitado  e já expandido para o usuário selecionar a opção dsejada.

Tentei dar o focu no campo ou disparar um `click` mas não consegui expandir, alguma sugestão?

```js
$("exibir").on("click", function(){
  $("#exemplo1").focus();
  $("#exemplo1").trigger("click");
  $("#exemplo1").click();
  $("#exemplo1").mousedown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="exemplo1" id="exemplo1">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="">Caique</option>
    <option value="">Natane</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <button name="exibir" id="exibir">
    Expandir select e exibir opções
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, acho entendi. Você quer expandir o select?

Comment: Como assim forçar a exibição da opções, mostrar aonde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente não tem como abrir o `select` programaticamente. Isso é uma restrição imposta pela política do navegador, onde deve haver uma interação direta do usuário.

No entanto há formas de manipular o elemento de modo a "simular" como se o `select` tivesse sido *clicado* e expandindo-o. A mais comum é transforma-lo em um *listbox*, adicionando a propriedade `size`.

Para fugir do comum, criei um script que pode ser aplicável ao seu caso. Consiste em *simular* um "select falso" que aplicando os estilos CSS fica quase idêntico ao `select` original tanto visualmente quanto funcionalmente.

Veja um exemplo com o código comentado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   function fakePop(el){
      // populo o falso select
      var val = el.find("option:selected").text();
      var opcoes = '';
      $.each(el.find("option"), function(e,t){
         var sel = $(t).text() == val ? ' class="selected"' : '';
         $("#fake_select").append('<li'+sel+'>'+$(t).text()+'</li>');
      });
   }

   $("#fake_select").on("mouseleave", function(){
      $("#fake_select").html('');
      var el = $("#exemplo1");
      fakePop(el);
   });

   // esconder o falso select
   function hideFakeSelect(){
      $("#fake_select").hide().html('');
   }
   
   $("#exibir").click(function(){
      
      var el = $("#exemplo1");
   
      if(!$("#fake_select").is(":visible")){
   
         // ajusto a posição e o tamanho do falso select
         $("#fake_select").css({
            "top": el.height()+"px",
            "width": el.width()+"px"
         }).show();
         
         fakePop(el); // populo o falso select

      }else{
         
         // escondo o falso select se ele estiver visível
         hideFakeSelect();
      }
   
   });
   
   $(document).on("click mouseover", "#fake_select li", function(e){
   
      // escondo o falso select ao clicar em uma opção
      if(e.type == "click"){
         $('#exemplo1').val($('#exemplo1 option:contains('+$(this).text()+')').val());
      }else{
         
         // efeito hover
         $("#fake_select li")
         .removeClass("selected")
         .not($(this));
      }
   }).on("click", function(){ // escondo o falso select ao clicar em uma opção ou em outro lugar da página
      hideFakeSelect();
   });

   // evito que o falso select feche ao clicar no botão
   $("#exibir").click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

```css
*{
   position: relative;
}

#fake_select{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 99;
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #999;
}

#fake_select li{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0 3px;
   cursor: default;
}

#fake_select .selected,
#fake_select li:hover{
   background: #3f81fb;
   color: #fff;
}

#exemplo1:focus + #fake_select{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="exemplo1" id="exemplo1">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Caique</option>
    <option value="2">Natane</option>
  </select>
  <span id="fake_select"></span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button name="exibir" id="exibir">
    Expandir select e exibir opções
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Show, muito bom.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei essa solução que pode te atender, pelo que entendi da sua pergunta... [Creditos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056666/expand-select-dropdown)

*OBS: Vc precisa fazer a parte de habilitar o Select, mas já é um caminho*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    
</style>
</head>
<body>


<select id="selecttest">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">free</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    <option value="5">five</option>
    <option value="6">six</option>
    <option value="7">seven</option>
    <option value="8">height</option>
    <option value="9">nine</option>
    <option value="10">ten</option>
    <option value="11">eleven</option>
    <option value="12">twelve</option>
    <option value="13">thirdteen</option>
</select>
    
<input type="button" value="Abrir" id="MyButton"/>

<script>
   $('#MyButton').on("click",function(){

$("#selecttest").attr("size", 8);
$("#selecttest").css("position","fixed");
$('#MyButton').css("margin-left", $("#selecttest").width() + 5);
});

$('#selecttest').on("change",function(){

$("#selecttest").attr("size", 1);

});
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui tem um modelo de Select do tipo readonly que tb pode te ajudar. Peguei na resposta de outra pergunta: [Creditos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128188/como-aplicar-readonly-em-um-select)

```css
select[readonly] {
  background: #eee; 
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<select readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" selected>Cliente</option>
  <option value="2">Contador</option>
  <option value="3">Vendedor</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

O que você procura é isso:

```html
<select id="teste" onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length" onmouseout="this.size=1" style="position:absolute">
  <option>ITEM1</option>
  <option>ITEM2</option>
  <option>ITEM3</option>
  <option>ITEM4</option>
  <option>ITEM5</option>
</select>
```

Faça o teste e informe o resultado.

Comment: Apesar da solução funcionar no onmouseover do elemento, eu não consigo fazer isso chamando diretamente no javascript e dessa forma também empurraria os elementos abaixo.Editei minha pergunta pois não estava muito clara. De qualquer forma não deixa de ser uma maneira de expandir o select.